# How to change buffer size for spidev on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi

I'm trying to transfer image data from a camera to the raspberry pi over SPI using the spidev interface. The maximum buffer size possible is 4096, I need about 200,000. [This](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-increase-the-buffer-of-spi/49726/4) suggested:

```
sudo su
cd /sys/module/spidev/parameters
chmod 666 bufsiz
echo 65534 > bufsiz
```

but every time I execute the last line I get:

```
root@raspberrypi:/sys/module/spidev/parameters# echo 65534 > bufsiz 
bash: echo: write error: Input/output error
```

I can see the file contents with:

```
cat bufsiz
```

which returns `4096` but I cannot change it. Here are the permissions in case they would be helpful:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 4096 May 28 14:23 bufsiz
```

any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have a read here https://www.sigmdel.ca/michel/ha/rpi/spi_on_pi_en.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](https://www.sigmdel.ca/michel/ha/rpi/spi_on_pi_en.html):

add `spidev.bufsiz=xxxx` to `/boot/cmdline.txt` and remember to keep everything on one line.

Comment: Well done. Thank you for sharing back with the community.

Comment: Thanks for your help!